# Manual vs Fusion360 calculation of natural frequency of beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, strength

I'm trying to uncover the natural frequency of a mass-less beam with 2 masses attached but getting different answers from Fusion360 vs a hand calculation.

[image: Beam and lengths displayed in a drawing]

L1=1m, L2=2m, m1=10kg, m2=20kg, Young's=210*10^9Pa, H=0,04m, B=0,02m I=H^3*B

My current way of calculating the natural frequencies via matlab is:

```
alpha11 = 2*L1^3 / (6*E*I);
alpha12 = L1^2*(3*L2-L1) / (6*E*I);
alpha21 = alpha12;
alpha22 = 2*L2^3 / (6*E*I);

A = [alpha11 alpha12
     alpha21 alpha22];

K = inv(A);

M = [m1 0
     0 m2];

omega_n = sqrt( eig(inv(M)*K) );
omega_1 = min(omega_n);
omega_2 = max(omega_n);

f1 = omega_1 / (2*pi);
f2 = omega_2 / (2*pi);
```

This results in f1 = 3,18 Hz & f2 = 28,57 Hz

When running the same beam in fusion the downwards natural frequencies are f1 = 29,4 Hz & f2 = 10279 Hz.

[image]

In fusion the beam had to be given a minimum density of 0,001 g/cm³.

What could be the cause for the natural frequencies differing this much? What am I doing wrong? Any help is deeply appreciated!

#### EDIT

To clarify the fusion setup. The beam is constrained against xyz-movement in the end. The masses are added as point-masses in the middle of the beam (only acting on a small area)

Comment: There are a things to clarify. First of all, the Mode you are presenting is Mode 9 (are you sure that the 10kHz frequency is the second frequency?). The second is that  I don't know how you simulated the $m_1$ and $m_2$ on the beam (Did you use a lumped mass or something else). Another way would be to distribute the lumped masses on the beam. If you do that then the density of the material should be in the order or 10g/cm^3 or greater. I suspect that tuning the density will play a significant role depending on how you setup your model.

Comment: I'm not skilled in this branch of mechanics, so these are generic suggestions: double-check the units in both your code and inputs to Fusion360 (m vs cm,  Pa vs kPa, etc).  What is "H" - not shown in diagram?  And if your diagram is to scale, "I" is greater than "B" but  $H^3 * B$ would be a very small number?    What are the values of modes 1 thru 8?  <-- and how does your MATLAB code identify modes?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The Matlab model only has 2 degree of freedom, so "counting modes" isn't hard to do!. Also, since 64-bit floating point can represent values between $\pm10^{\pm 300}$ you don't have to worry about overflow or underflow unless you are calculating something very weird.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but $I = h^3b/12$, not $h^3b$

Comment: @alephzero I wasn't worried about floating-point accuracy -- just that the diagram didn't seem to match the values.  In looking again, I see that the beam dimensions are "H" and "B" but he drew the "H" sideways so I thought that was the "I"  .  Sorry about that.

Comment: It is hard to see from the image, but the two masses appear to have virtually 0 displacement in mode 9 and all of the displacement is in the beams. That is unexpected.  What do modes 1 and 2 look like?